# Why img.onload() function not working on ipad for exporting my chart data in pdf format?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to export my chart data consisting of image and data in a PDF. It works fine for me in laptop browser, but while I am trying to do the same in Ipad, the img.onload() function is not firing. I am not sure but I feel like it is due to the size of the image that is rendering in it. Can anybody help me with it? Can we change the pixels of the image that is being rendered?

```
The code is given below:-

 function exportData(exportType) {
            if (exportType) {
                if (exportType == "pdf") {
                    alert("clicked pdf")
                    console.log("pdf export ....")
                    vm.toggleCanvas = !vm.toggleCanvas;
                    var canvas = "";
                    var ctxt = "";
                    // var img = "";
                    var sheets = "";
                    var svgURL = "";
                    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                    $log.log($window.screen.width)
                    //resizing image for PDF
                    if ($window.screen.width >= 1500) {
                        canvas.width = $window.screen.width - 150;
                    } else {
                        canvas.width = $window.screen.width;
                    }
                    console.log("before canvas")
                    ctxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    sheets = document.styleSheets;
                    svgURL = generateSVGWithStyling('svg');
                    // var img = document.createElement('img');
                    var img = new Image();
                    console.log("after image")
                    console.log(img)
                    alert("imb")
                    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgURL);


                    img.onload = function () {
                        debugger
                        console.log("in load")
                        alert("in load")
                        ctxt.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                        vm.cnvasImg = "";
                        vm.cnvasImg = canvas.toDataURL();
                        var content = "";
                        console.log("on load")
                        subExportData(vm.cnvasImg, exportType);
                    }



                    console.log(img.src)

                } else {
                    vm.cnvasImg = "nothing";
                    subExportData(vm.cnvasImg, exportType);
                }

            }
        }
```

Any help would be apprciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting a smaller width and height for the canvas element ...?

Comment: If I give a basic image of 110 x 120 px to img.src, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with passing the width, height properties to Image constructor Object.

`var img = new Image(Width, Height);`